# How can I post multi-dimensional array using jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, json, ajax

I have an array like that `{{0,0},{1,1},{2,2}}` that is a javascript variable. I tried to post it using JSON.Stringify but it gave internal server error 500. How can I post and use it?

Here is My jquery Code:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: myJsonData,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
    crossDomain:true,
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (response) {
        $("#Content").text(response.d);
        console.log(response.d);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
        console.log(response.d);
    }
});
```

And Here is my server side code:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetLocationPolygon(string location) {

        return location;
    }
```

Comment: If the error is an internal server error, you should probably check your server logs, and see what fails.

Comment: as @user3663216 said, you are using object notation, change your code or `myJsonData` to be a valid aray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[] is array, {} is object. objects must have key value pairs.

so either..

```
{0:{0:0},1:{1:1},2:{2:2}}
```

or

```
[[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]]
```

to fix it..